# jquery .html value not return codebehinde asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox

i write jquery  calculation text box it works fine on page but i get value of Textbox it shows null

```
$(function() {
  $("[id*=txttotalprice]").val("0");
});

$("body").on("change keyup", "[id*=txttotalprice]", function() {
  var grandTotal = 0;
  $("[id*=txttotalprice]").each(function() {
    grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(grandTotal.toString());
  $("#<%=lblGrandTotal12.ClientID%>").val(grandTotal.toString());
});
```

Comment: Can u post html of that input?